# Weird transient leaking faucet/tap

Tags: leak, faucet

I have this mixer tap which has recently developed strange symptoms:

[image]

It leaks for a little while after every time we use it, with a kind of gurgly emptying noise. What's strange is that it will also do this when someone upstairs or downstairs (we're in an apartment block) turns their water on. On top of that, it doesn't seem to make much difference whether it's the hot or cold which is turned on.

[image]

I've tried having a look inside to see if I could replace the washers, but I can't actually work out how to get much further in. Taking the C-clip out doesn't seem to make the cartridge release, and the brass fitting looks/feels like it is welded (originally or by age?) to the body.

Any ideas on possible causes and possible solutions?

(NB: not in the US)

Comment: Does the stem move in-and-out when turned or just change its angle?The purpose of the C-clip is not clear to me. If the rib or flange on top of the C-clip turns with the handle *and* the stem moves in-and-out, then the c-clip could be a stop. Does the groove where the c-clip sits have flats on it or is it round?

Comment: Another possibility is that the C-clip positions the stem in the valve so that it cannot mover further in.  If the clip is removed and the flange is not part of the stem but is part of the cap that appears to thread into the valve body (valve body with the large flats on it) then one could use a pipe wrench or locking pliers to unscrew the cap and the valve stem from the valve body. Use a large wrench on the large flats to counter-hold the valve body in place.

Comment: @JimStewart, thanks. I tried but it didn't seem to work. Next I'm going to try unscrewing the whole thing, but only when I've got time to run to the store if it goes wrong!

Comment: I suppose it is possible that the cap is pressed into the main part of the valve body rather than screwed and not removable. Is this an inexpensive faucet? If so, it might not be repairable.

Comment: If you try unscrewing the whole thing, you *might* have to disconnect the supply line from the bottom because it *might* twist the supply line. It may not be that way though so you would have to examine it underneath to see how it is connected. Good luck. I think it might be time for a replacement.

Comment: @JimStewart, answered my own question, just in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
This was the culprit.
It had a leak in, and for some reason was effectively syphoning all of the water out of the spout. Which explained the gurgling.

Before discovering this, I did change the washers. As @JimStewart said in his comments, the whole of the brass thing unscrewed and the washer/plunger was underneath.

Comment: Where does that part go? It's not visible in the pictures.

Comment: @Johnny, it screws on the spout so that you can point the water in the direction you want. Also reduces flow (I think) and creates a cleaner jet of water.

Comment: Ugh, "jet of water". Good job this isn't English.SE :)